# Creating Combo Box UserControl with Multi Column

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, user-controls

I have multi-column combo box but i want to use these combo box in many places.So I think i need to create combo box user control.But problem is itemsource of each combo box is not same.

Currently my multi column combo box,

```
 <ComboBox Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="1"                       
                       Margin="2"
                      Width="150"
                    x:Name="cboemployee"
                      IsEditable="True"   
                     DisplayMemberPath="EmployeeID"
                    SelectedValuePath="EmployeeID" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding  EmployeeList}">                   
                    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroComboBoxItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Grid Width="400" x:Name="gd">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock Margin="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding EmployeeID}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Margin="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding EmployeeName}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="ComboBoxItem.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                                <Setter TargetName="gd"  Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource AccentBaseColorBrush}"></Setter>
                                                <Setter TargetName="gd"  Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="ComboBoxItem.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                <Setter TargetName="gd"  Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource AccentColorBrush}"></Setter>
                                                <Setter TargetName="gd"  Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>                  
                </ComboBox>
```

I am not sure i need custom combo box or combo box user control and Please let me known which is best for my requirement with binding different item source?

Comment: All you need to do is put everything in a Style as a resource and reference it wherever you need it

Comment: @DaveM How about different itemsource?I means current i bind `EmployeeList` but next combo I want to bind `UserList`.So obviously this will reflect to which property will display in ControlTemplate. Thank you

Comment: You only said the ItemsSource would be different in your question, I took that literally.

Comment: I assume you mean the Binding to EmployeeID and EmployeeName in the ControlTemplate will also need to be different? If so, you should make a more generic ControlTemplate that doesn’t need to directly bind to data (typically ControlTemplates use TemplateBinding instead of Binding)

Comment: @DaveM Please can you show me sample (or) link for generic ControlTemplate?